# Are there "place cells" for temporal encoding?

Tags: neuroscience, perception, memory, time, spatial-cognition

First of all, I have to say I am not a neuroscientist but I like to learn about neuroscience. I understand there are sets of neurons called "place cells" and "grid cells" which encode spatial information in the brain.

My question is simple: Is there a structure in the brain known to encode **temporal** information analogous to place cells? Is anyone aware of some references or experiments on this subject?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the topic of time perception is quite complicated. In contrast to the place and grid cells in the hippocampus [(Moser *et al*., 2015)](https://cshperspectives.cshlp.org/content/7/2/a021808.full), the perception of time seems to be distributed across many places in the brain. A review by [Fontes *et al*., 2016)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4830363/) cites 158 papers written between 1980 to 2015 that describe a variety of brain structures relating to the perception of time, including areas in the **frontal cortex, parietal cortex, basal ganglia, cerebellum and hippocampus**. It indeed seems to be a [highly distributed system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_perception#Neuroscientific_perspectives) in the brain. The proximity of time cells and place and grid cells in the hippocampus is interesting and is an [active area of research](https://www.ntnu.edu/how-your-brain-experiences-time#:%7E:text=Researchers%20at%20the%20Kavli%20Institute,experience%2C%20says%20Professor%20Edvard%20Moser.).

<sub>**References**

**-** [Fontes *et al*., *Neurol Int* (2016); **8**(1): 59392016](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4830363/)

**-** [Moser *et al*., Cold Spring Harb Perspect Biol (2015); **7**: a021808](https://cshperspectives.cshlp.org/content/7/2/a021808.full)</sub>